# Is there any way to get the update date in linq and c#?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any way to get the date of the last update of a row or cell using linq and c#? or to retrieve the update dates?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What's your dataset like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a LINQ issue. It's a database issue. You should have a timestamp field on your table, or an identity field (autonumber).

If you have a timestamp field (or a simple datetime) field, then you can:

```
var lastField = dataContext
                .EntitySet
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.DateTimeField)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

And if you have a auto-increment, auto-number field (an identity field), you might write:

```
var lastField = dataContext
                .EntitySet
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a column that you defined as 'last updated' or something. Then keep it maintained whenever you update the record.

This is not an inherent property of databases. You have to create your table with this in mind.